# fail2ban nginx ignoreregex not working

Tags: nginx, fail2ban

I have a rails app, and the requests related to assets are to be ignored. If I put the following regex in the `ignoreregex` setting, it doesnt match any of the lines, whereas, if I put it in the `failregex`, it correctly identifies the lines.

`ignoreregex =   (?i)^<HOST> - .* "GET .*/(assets|site_images|site_scripts)/.*`

The example of the log line that I would like to count as to be "ignored":

`XX.XX.XX.XX - - [30/Aug/2017:02:01:40 +0000] "GET /assets/logo-1a29bc0c23e29be7ca1f27d9fd90d735adb61e94562db7478d9f6c445205da5c.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 32279 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) wkhtmltopdf_linux_amd64 Safari/534.34" "-"`

Fail2Ban version: v0.9.3

Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Comment: Maybe you can try to test using `fail2ban-regex <logfile> <failregex> <ignoreregex>` to see the results. So you can test `fail2ban-regex /path/to/your/log /path/to/your/filter /path/to/your/filter`. If the ignore filter is on the same file as failregex file.

Comment: Another idea... try to put $ to finish the line of each regex. so `(?i)^<HOST> - .* "GET .*/(assets|site_images|site_scripts)/.*$` and the same for failregex.